# SQL Is "Delete all records, then add them again" instantly bad practice?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I have a mvvm WPF application. In my view im showing a represantation of essentially 3 Tables. Table A is the main object. Table B and A have a n-n relationship. I have a join Table to connect the two

So in the actual app, you can select/deselect your B objects and i managed to have a correct represantation of whats selected/picked in the model.

My Problem comes in, when object B was initially selected, then gets deselected, and then selected again. I have a "new" B object in my model A, with no "ID" anymore to check whether it was newly created or whether an entry in the DB already exists.

Basically i have to decide between implementing some kinda mechanism that keeps track of which selection to create / update / delete with all possibilities. OR just delete all records -> add records according to my model.

Option #2 seems a lot simpler to me, but also not super clean.

Im wondering how bad is it really though? It's a small amount of data, that probably won't get updated very often.

Edit Clarification: Its not code, but its the best way i can think to explain it.

So i start loading my Customer object, it has a list of CustomerGroups. In the underlying DB i have a Table Customers, a table Groups, and a table Customer_Groups to join them.

Initially my Customer / Screen looks like this

```
[ ] 1
[x] 2   (ID: 67, Group: 2, Customer: 5)
[ ] 3
[ ] 4
[x] 5   (ID: 30, Group: 5, Customer: 5)
```

Then the user deselects Group 2.

```
[ ] 1
[ ] 2   
[ ] 3
[ ] 4
[x] 5   (ID: 30, Group: 5, Customer: 5)
```

Then he adds group 2 again, but since it wasnt selected last time, my in memory object gets a newly generated associated group object.

```
[ ] 1
[x] 2   (ID: NULL, Group: 2, Customer: 5)
[ ] 3
[ ] 4
[x] 5   (ID: 30, Group: 5, Customer: 5)
```

Just writing this out, i thought of a way to do it. I write a smarter query that checks if an entry for **group X Customer Y** already exists, then update if exists, else create it... I was too focused on the ID.

Comment: When you say "delete the data" you mean in-memory data right? Or are you actually deleting/truncating the data via SQL?  I don't see any reason for the latter, when you can handle everything in-memory.  Could you use ViewBag to keep that "B" objects present without losing it, especially if it's not much data like you mentioned.

Comment: Could you put in a code example? It is hard to understand why either object would ever not have an ID after it has been committed to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be a problem to recreate these associations if are not updated very often.

Now if it was a query/process that was constantly deleting/re-associating the records then yes, you probably would want to avoid that.

Best way to avoid the issue of accidentally removing/re-adding the association is to update the View/ViewModel code with a save button that will commit the changes when the user is finished instead of doing the SQL update directly after each user interaction. 

I wouldn't try to recover the deleted association record. Though that is possible with a deleted flag column if you'd like. But what will result in is a bunch of unnecessary rows that are there in case you'd like to re-add the link by clearing the flag.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the item created in your DB already for the link up, I would just create a new object that inherits that DBO and has an IsSelected property on it that we can bind to the checkbox. When the user saves, you can loop through your list of objects and see if an item is selected but has no ID then add it to the DB. If an item is not selected but has an ID you can remove it from the DB.
You could also look at the check_changed event and just update that specific item if the user isn't clicking a save button.